# Why isn't this Git commit garbage collected?

Tags: git, garbage-collection, commit

I found a commit (using `git log --all`) that is not on any branch.

```
$ git show ffeb1787af33993ee9658f42337f2688013cbcb8
commit ffeb1787af33993ee9658f42337f2688013cbcb8
...
$ git branch --contains ffeb1787af33993ee9658f42337f2688013cbcb8
```

After `git gc` etc. it is still there.

It must be held onto to by some other ref, such as a tag.

How can I find why this commit is still in my repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
git name-rev ffeb1787af33993ee9658f42337f2688013cbcb8
```

It will attempt to compute a symbolic name for that SHA based on what, if any, chain it's in.

Comment: Awesome. `ffeb1787af33993ee9658f42337f2688013cbcb8 tags/1.0-rc1006~1`, so it's one commit before the tag 1.0-rc1006.

Comment: It could also be references in the reflog (but you did not search for those). But they are also not GCed.